# startActivity is executing, but no Activity is launched

Tags: android, android-intent

I have these two activities in my manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".ProgressPhotos"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

I want on an item clicked in Progress Photos to launch DetailsActivity:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);
    ....
```

So, in ProgressPhotos I setup this on click listener:

```
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                  //Create intent
                Intent viewDetails = new Intent(ProgressPhotos.this,DetailsActivity.class);
                viewDetails.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                viewDetails.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

                //Start details activity
                try {
                    startActivity(viewDetails);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    // log statement here
                }

      }
    });
```

I have setup break points throughout the entire listener. Each one is clicked, and an exception is never thrown.

However, the onCreate of DetailsActivity is *never* called. It never gets launched, but every line is executed. How? I've tried changing "ProgressPhotos.this" to getApplication Context, and the same response. No error is thrown. What could it be?

Comment: Did you declare DetailActivity in your Manifest?

Comment: Instead of `ProgressPhotos.this`, try just `this` in the intent

Comment: @frankelydiaz yes. Quote above.

Comment: @DavidM it won't let me since it's inside an listener. To Quote, "Can't resolve constructor".

Comment: you can declare a final variable to hold the "this" before the listener. final ProgressPhotos currentActivity = this;

Comment: @frankelydiaz nope, same response :(.

Comment: Could you remove the try/catch ?

Comment: Try/catch removed, using final context earlier declared, same response. No error is thrown.

Comment: remove extras from intent and try to put log in first line in DetailsActivity. Check if the log is printed or not.

Comment: @user3265443 ... okay, removing the extras worked for some strange reason. It opens up now. I even put the extras back in, and it stopped opening the activity.

Comment: @sparkysword have you tried using diferent keys? A have a feeling that the system uses "title" key somehow.

Comment: try to pass some hard coded values to same keys..If this works, which means there could be some  item object instance fields